# JSF 1.2 to open external link in new tab. without distrubing current flow

Tags: jsf, tabs, jsf-1.2

I want to open https://stackoverflow.com/ in another tab but don't want to disturb current tab execution.

This is what I have tried -

```
try{
            ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
            externalContext.redirect("https://stackoverflow.com");
        } catch(Exception e){
            throw new FacesException("Redirection failed");
        }
```

currently, this code is opening this URL in the current tab only i.e. my current execution is going away.

Comment: I would expect IBM to have internal experts on this btw...

Comment: :) Thanks for your suggestion.